# Using CGAL 5.1 with third party Libraries

Tags: cmake, cgal

I am trying to compile the example read_las_example.cpp in CGAL examples directory ***Point_set_processing_3***.

However `cmake` command runs into the error:

```
include could not find load file:

    CGAL_LASLIB_support
```

There are some directions on using CGAL with third party libraries here : https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/thirdparty.html#thirdpartyLASlib
but I am not able to follow it. In particular I don't understand how to do this -  "*the executables should be linked with the CMake imported target CGAL::LASLIB_support provided in CGAL_LASLIB_support.cmake*". If it helps, the ***CGAL_LASLIB_support.cmake*** file is located in the directory ***cgal/5.1/lib/cmake/CGAL***

Can anyone help with how to use CGAL with third party libraries, in particular LASlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you need to include `CGAL_LASLIB_support` and call `target_link_libraries(your_exe_name CGAL::LASLIB_support)`
It is already used in the example's CmakeLists.txt, you should check that the CGAL you are using is really 5.1, not another version cached somewhere in your system. The target `CGAL::LASLIB_support` only exists since 5.1, so the error seems to indicate that the CGAL version you are using is not the right one.

Comment: Thanks. Being new to CMake, I didn't know how to make use of CGAL_LASLIB_support.  Just for completion, I had to add the directory of CGAL_LASLIB_support to module path of CMake. This, I achieved by adding following line to CMakeLists.txt : list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "<path to CGAL_LASLIB_support.cmake>"). I am sure there is a way to do this in command line while calling CMake as well but I don't know the way yet. Do you ?

Comment: I'm surprised it is not already the case with simply the CGAL_DIR

Comment: Yes, I wonder if I missed some setting during installation. 
Also, if it helps you, the LASlib which comes with LAS tools is not working. I had to use the LASlib fork provided by CGAL.

Comment: Yes, that is what specified in CGAL's doc. For the module path, you must have done something wrong, because it is set by CGAL's CMake scripts already. You shouldn't have to edit any existing CMakeLists for any reason.

Comment: I see. I had actually updated the version from 5.0 to 5.1. Maybe that's the reason. But anyways, good that I know things a bit more explicitly now. Thank you.